# Control KineticJS rotation from center of shape?

Tags: javascript, rotation, kineticjs

I'm making a game and I really want asthetic (sorry if I spelled that wrong) stars in my background.

I am completely fine with making a `Kinetic.Line` and making it look like a star, it's just the rotation I'm having problems with.  You see, I want the star to rotate from the center, not the upper left corner.


For anybody who has ever seen an animated twinkling star, they rotate from the center, not the upper left corner.


So I'm at a loss for what do do.  Trigonometry, maybe?  Probably not, though.  Maybe subtracting half of the width from the x and same for the y...?  I don't know.


Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I just realized there is a method for that - `offset`.